# Filter on Custom BaseAdapter not working

Tags: android, filter, baseadapter

I have a BaseAdapter and want use filter it. Its filled with object (1). I want filter using the field "nome". Its give me error when i try use the filter. check the code:

Object Contato

```
public class Contato {
    public static final String CONTATO_NOME = "contato_nome";
    public static final String CONTATO_ORG = "contato_org";
    public static final String CONTATO_ID = "contato_id";

    public static String[] colunas = {"_id", Contato.CONTATO_NOME, Contato.CONTATO_ORG, Contato.CONTATO_ID};

    public long _id;
    public String nome;
    public String org;
    public String id;

    public Contato () {
    }

    public Contato (String nome, String org, String id) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.org = org;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Contato (long _id, String nome, String org, String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.org = org;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static String[] getColunas() {
        return colunas;
    }
    public static void setColunas(String[] colunas) {
        Contato.colunas = colunas;
    }

    public long get_Id() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void set_Id(long _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getOrg() {
        return org;
    }
    public void setOrg(String org) {
        this.org = org;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

baseadapter

```
public class ContatoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<Contato> lista;
    private TextView nome;
    private TextView org;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ContatoListAdapter(Context contexto, List<Contato> lista) {
        this.context = contexto;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Recupera a atividade da posição atual
        Contato c = lista.get(position);

        if (position == 0) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contato_linha_lista, null);
            // Atualiza o valor do TextView
            nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtContatoListaNome);
            nome.setText(c.nome);

            org = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtContatoListaOrganizacao);
            org.setText(c.org);

            return view;

        } else {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contato_linha_lista, null);

            // Atualiza o valor do TextView
            nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtContatoListaNome);
            nome.setText(c.nome);

            org = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtContatoListaOrganizacao);
            org.setText(c.org);

            return view;

        }
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                lista = (List<Contato>) results.values;
                ContatoListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                List<Contato> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }
        };
    }

    protected List<Contato> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

filter's call

```
Util.etxtTelaContatosListaBuscar
                .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {
                    }

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int before, int count) {
                        if (Util.adapter != null)
                            Util.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    }
                });
```

EDIT:

errors I got after type something in search field:

> Shutting down VM
>
> thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at
>   com.datalabrasil.dtldiscover.ContatoListAdapter.getCount(ContatoListAdapter.java:28)
>
> at
>   android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:778)
>
> at
>   android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:31)
>
> at
>   android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
>
> at
>   com.datalabrasil.dtldiscover.ContatoListAdapter$1.publishResults(ContatoListAdapter.java:85)
>
> at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
>
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Would be really useful if you appended the error you get to your question.

Comment: As a note, you don't need the get/set methods in your Contato class. Since each member is `public` you can access them directly with `String name = contato1.name` and `contato1.name = "George"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected List<Contato> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

i think you have to fill this method's body, returning proper result :)

**edit:** try this:

```
protected List<Contato> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) {
    ArrayList<Contacto> filteredList = new ArrayList<Contato>(); 
    for (Contato c:lista) { 
        if (c.nome.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().trim().toLowerCase())) { // you can also use contains instead of startsWith...whatever you need 
            filteredList.add(c); 
        } 
    } 
    return filteredList;
    }
```

**edit #2:** in the for cycle would be maybe better to use something like `getAllContato()` or something like that, instead of lista, because after filtering, filtered results rewrite variable lista and that means that with every filtering, you will have less and less items in your list...in that case you are filtering filtered items and so on...i hope you get what i am trying to say. :)

Comment: well, i didnt understand well the logic behind this filter, so i dont know what put in this method.

Comment: try something like this: `ArrayList<Contacto> filteredList = new ArrayList<Contato>();
for (Contato c:lista) {
 if (c.nome.startsWith(constraint)) { /* you can also use c.nome.contains...whatever you need */
  filteredList.add(c);
 }
}
return filteredList;`

Comment: its works, but my list doesnt back even I erase all data in search field. I'll try something to get it back. Even I put "c.nome.contains(constrain)", its not filter letters means, for example: have contact that begins with the letter A and and another that has the same letter at the end of it, if I type A in search field, its only filter the first contact, the other is not shown.

Comment: look at my **edit #2**, maybe that is the point :) thanks for accepting